# Inno setup with IKG : Access violation at address XXXXXXX in module ISID.dll

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup Key Generator (IKG). I successfully call ValidateSerialNumber

```
Valid := ValidateSerialNumber(ExpPath,RegName,'','','','',PrivKey,RegKey);
```

As long as I pass empty Strings for PrivKey and RegKey the function returns false as expected. As soon as I pass a value to PrivKey or RegKey I get the Error Message:

```
Access violation at address XXXXXXX in module ISID.dll. Read of Address XXXXXX.
```

Non-empty values for ExpPath or RegName do not have this effect.

The function is declared:

```
function ValidateSerialNumber(InnoKeyFile, User, Orgn, ProdCode, HDD, MAC, PrivateKey, 
Serial: String): Boolean;
external 'ValidateSerialNumber@files:ISID.dll stdcall';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of InnoSetup are you using, Unicode or ANSI version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use are most probably using Unicode InnoSetup and that library counts with the ANSI version. I 've found [`some manual`](http://www.mjfreelancing.com/downloads/ikg/ikghelppdf.zip) for that library from the year 2004, when the [`InnoSetup wasn't Unicode`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/files/is5-whatsnew.htm#5.3.0) yet, so try to use this ANSI import:

```
function ValidateSerialNumber(InnoKeyFile, User, Orgn, ProdCode, HDD, MAC, PrivateKey,
  Serial: AnsiString): Boolean;
  external 'ValidateSerialNumber@files:ISID.dll stdcall';
```

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad it helped, but please include into your question that you're using Unicode version of InnoSetup. My answer was just a guess that fortunately worked :-) Welcome to StackOverflow, anyway!